# I am trying to replace the Tooltip placeholder, $i18n{tooltipZoomOut}, in a PDF file loaded into TChromium

Tags: delphi, pdf, localization, tooltip, chromium

I have a Delphi 10.3 application and it uses `TChromium` to load local HTML files.

This works fine, and I can navigate to a PDF in the same window and it loads via Chrome's PDF handler.

The only problem I have is when hovering over the default buttons in the PDF viewer (such as Zoomin, print etc), I get what looks like the tooltip placeholder before it gets replaced with localized text.

`$i18n{tooltipZoomOut}` is the tooltip on the zoom out button, instead of nicer tooptip text. I can not find how to change this. I am not sure if it's something I can configure within Delphi or if I need to include a language file which Chromium will use.

Comment: Doesn't sound like "trying", only like "wanting". Using the `OnTooltip` event would be my first attempt.

Comment: @AmigoJack, Thanks for the suggestion, I tried the onToopTip event, as you suggested, on the Chromiuim component. It didn't trigger when in the pdf reader, I added a basic showmessage in the ontooltip event.

I assigned the function via the editor and also tried adding it in code but both did not trigger the event.